# Is $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ the unique compact connected Lie group acting transitively and faithfully on the sphere $ S^2 $?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, group-actions, homogeneous-spaces

Is $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ the unique compact connected Lie group acting transitively and faithfully and smoothly on the sphere $ S^2 $?

The point stabilizer of the action will be a closed connected subgroup of codimension 2 (connected because the quotient is simply connected).

@mme says in answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408648/is-so4-a-subgroup-of-su3: "Here is an additional, more straightforward, argument. If H⊂G is codimension 2, then G/H is a surface. An element of g acts trivially on G/H if gg′H=g′H for all g′, which amounts to saying that every conjugate of g lies in H, which amounts to saying that g lies in the intersection of all conjugates of H, which is a normal subgroup of G (call it K). Now G/K is a subgroup of the isometry group of a surface, hence at most 3 dimensional. When g is simple K must be 0-dimensional and dimG≤3."

Maybe that helps?

Comment: What are your thoughts? In particular, do you assume smoothness of the action (which makes the proof simpler)?

Comment: Oh sure I meant to assume smooth I don't care about topological groups and ya I'm sure it's true but no idea how to prove it because this kind of uniqueness fails when we relax connectedness O_3 or relax compactness PSL_2(C) or go to higher dimension SU_2 and SO_4 both act on S^3 or relax faithfulness or relax transitivity

Comment: Please, update your question accordingly. A hint: what will be the point stabilizer isomorphic to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch of one possible argument:

Let $G$ be a connected compact Lie group acting faithfully, smoothly, and transitively on $S^2$, and let $h$ be an arbitrary Riemannian metric on $S^2$. Let $h'$ be the $G$-invariant "average" of $h$, defined by
$$
h'=\int_Gg^*(h)\omega(g)
$$
where $\omega$ is the normalized Haar measure on $G$. Since $G$ acts transitively and isometrically, $h'$ has constant curvature, and is thus $(S^2,h')$ is isometric to a round sphere $(S^2,\mathring{h}_r)$. This gives an inclusion $i:G\to SO(3)$, and it's straightforward to argue that $i$ is also an isomorphism.

Comment: Ah I see so if G is not assumed connected we just get an embedding into O_3 and then the two possibilities for G are O_3 and SO_3. So does this show in general that a compact group acting faithfully transitively smoothly on the sphere S^n must be a subgroup of O_{n+1}?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira No; the issue is that "constant curvature" becomes a more subtle matter in dimension $>2$. In order for this argument to work there, we would need $(S^n,h')$ to have constant *sectional* curvature, which would not necessarily be the case unless $G$ acts transitively on the Grassmannian bundle $Gr(TS^n,2)$.